# Punctuation in a list

Tags: academic-writing, punctuation

Let's say I have a document with a list like this:

- aaaa
- bbbb
- cccc
- dddd

Should I put nothing, a semicolon, a full stop or what at the end of each line?  This is for an academic paper.  We don't have a specific style guide we're supposed to follow.

I found some information on the Internet and apparently: if there is no full stop within an item (as in 2nd and 3rd item in the list above), the item is closed by a semicolon, otherwise by a full stop (as in the 1st item in the list above).

Is this correct?

Is this applicable to a mixed (full stop within some item, no full stop within some other time) list?

Answer (score 3):

This is a stylistic choice. I would never use a comma or semicolon at the end of a list item. I would use a period/full stop only if the item is a full sentence. To wit:

> *Star Trek* is known for breaking new ground on television in several ways:
>
> • Kirk and Uhura's kiss in "Plato's Stepchildren" was the first interracial kiss on broadcast TV.
>
> • Chekov (a Russian) and Uhura (a black woman) as bridge officers
>
> • An alien as the first officer (and in the pilot, a woman as the first officer)
>
> • In later series, black and female captains, and a Klingon bridge officer
>
> • Apocryphally, Lt. Malcolm Reed was intended to be gay, which would have made all the security officers contravene the hulking testosterone-soaked bruiser stereotype (Yar, a wasp-waisted woman; Worf, the oddly subdued Klingon; Odo, the thoughtful shapeshifter; Tuvok, a Vulcan; and Reed, a slender gay man).

Comment: I think the only time to have commas, etc at the end of list items is if the entire list makes a sentence.

Comment: @NeilFein I might let that go as an editor, but I'd never write it that way.

Comment: I generally agree with this, but I find it very hard to mix sentences (with periods) and fragments (without) in a single list.  Once I've written a sentence and thus put a period at the end of one of them, I want to write the others as sentences so they'll get punctuation too, for consistency.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Absolutely. I wrote the list above as a mix purely for the sake of the example. If I were writing it for myself, I would make the grammar parallel — either all phrases (no periods) or all sentences (with periods).

Comment: Agreed. Also, I never knew that about Lt. Reed. I'm gonna have to re-watch some *Enterprise* now.

Comment: @NeilFein Dominic Keating mentioned it in a *TVGuide* interview just before the series debuted, but B&B never did much with the idea. The only real allusion (besides Mal & Trip's obvious affection) was in "E2," where the alternate history recorded that Malcolm never sired children. Keating somewhat jokingly confirmed that he did play Mal as gay. (And Mirror Reed swishes a lot, which was definitely deliberate and intentionally over-the-top campy.)

Answer (score 1):

To me, there are two options:

**1. Your list is a list**

> The following fruits are healthy:
>
> - apples
> - bananas
> - cherrys
>
> I love to eat them.

Lists don't have punctuation. Even if each list item is a full sentence, you don't need to put a full stop after it (unless it is a quote).

> What you need to remember:
>
> 1. Sleep well
> 2. Eat well
> 3. Love your parents

If your list lists sentences, list them with the punctuation:

> ```
> "Come home."
> But Joan only shook her head. (from John Jake, The Boring Book)
> ```
>
> These are my favourite sentences from John Jake's *Boring Book:*
>
> 1. "Come home."
> 2. But Joan only shook her head.

Both list items are understood to be quotes from a text, that is, the first sentence was written with quotation marks in the original.

**2. Your list is a sentence styled as a list**

> I love to eat
>
> - oranges,
> - bananas, and
> - apples,
>
> because they are healthy.

Sentences have punctuation.